# Syntax error(missing error) in query expression

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

```
If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtadmin.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtname.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtcourse.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtic.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtgender.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtaddress.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtbirth.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txttel.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtemail.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txttpye.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the on the box.", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim Conn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\temp\Database1.accdb"
    Conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)


    Try
    If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Conn.Close()
    Conn.Open()    

Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_info ([AdminNo],UserName, [Course Title], ICNo, Gender, Address, [Data of Birth], TelNo, Email, Type) values ('" & txtname.Text & "', '" & txtadmin.Text & "', '" & txtcourse.Text & "', '" & txtic.Text & "', '" & txtgender.Text & "', '" & txtaddress.Text & "','" & txtbirth.Text & "', '" & txttel.Text & "', '" & txtemail.Text & "', '" & txttpye.Text & "')"
Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)
sqlCom.Connection = Conn

Dim result As Integer = sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery 

sqlCom.Dispose()
Conn.Close()
```

There is a "Syntax error(missing error) in query expression "233 sangkeng st #6-12 (s'451233')"" error at this line:

```
Dim result As Integer = sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery
```

but in address i anyhow write like **ggghh** it can get it

```
If result > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully created.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Failure to create.")
    End If

    txtname.Text = ""
    txtadmin.Text = ""
    txtcourse.Text = ""
    txtic.Text = ""
    txtgender.Text = ""
    txtaddress.Text = ""
    txtbirth.Text = ""
    txttel.Text = ""
    txtemail.Text = ""
    txttpye.Text = ""
    txtadmin.Focus()



    'Catch ex As Exception
    'MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to Database..", "Database Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    'End Try
```

Comment: format your question properly

Comment: Never use string concatenation to insert values into SQL code.  Always use parameters.  Do that and your issue goes away.  http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Answer (score 2):

You didn't account for the single quotes in your data. **Don't use string concatentation to include fields in your queries!** It not only leaves you open to errors like this, but also some truly awful security problems.

```
Dim Result As Integer
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_info ([AdminNo],UserName, [Course Title], ICNo, Gender, Address, [Data of Birth], TelNo, Email, Type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

Using conn As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"), _
       cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)

    'I'm guessing at the DB types here. Use the actual types from your database.
    cmd.Parameters.Add("AdminNo", OleDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = txtadmin.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("UserName", OleDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = txtname.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Course Title", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = txtcourse.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ICNo", OleDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = txtic.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Gender", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = txtgender.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Address", OleDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = txtaddress.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Date of Birth", OleDbType.DateTime).Value =  CDate(txtbirth.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("TelNo", OleDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = txttel.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Email", OleDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtemail.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Type", OleDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = txttpye.Text

    conn.Open()
    result = cmd.ExecuteNonquery()
End Using
```

Side note: I don't really ever use column names with spaces, and so I'm not sure I have the format right for the first argument to the Parameters.Add() call in a couple places above. You may still need to use the square brackets with the names in this situation.

Comment: I was just about to post an answer referencing a previous post you made on this subject.

Comment: I've written about this a _lot_ -- it's a common (and very serious) problem -- so that doesn't narrow it down much. Why don't you go ahead and post the link?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, kudos; I was going to use one of your previous answers on another post as a reference for answering this post, but you beat me to it.